# scala assert objects equals

Tags: scala, mockito

in my scala test, i need to verify some method was invoked twice on an object `emailPermissionModel` and i captured the arguments when the method was invoked, and finally i compared the captured arguments with my expected results, even thought the printout of the captured argument and expected result were same but test still failed, i cannot figure out why.

here is my test code:

```
val emailPermissionDtoCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[EmailPermissionDTO])
verify(emailPermissionModel, times(2)).storePermission(emailPermissionDtoCaptor.capture())
val capturedemailPermissionDto = emailPermissionDtoCaptor.getAllValues

val expectedEmailPermDto1 = EmailPermissionDTO(
                EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                "topic1",
                "1995-09-09")
expectedEmailPermDto1.equals(capturedemailPermissionDto.get(0).asInstanceOf[EmailPermissionDTO]) ==> it return false
```

i also tried this, still return false:

```
expectedEmailPermDto1 == capturedemailPermissionDto.get(0).asInstanceOf[EmailPermissionDTO])
```

Comment: I've never worked on mockito, but I know that `return` keyword must not be used in return statement in Scala.

Comment: It would be good to see what is in capturedemailPermissionDto to answer.

Comment: Any reason for not doing `verify(emailPermissionModel, times(2)).storePermission(EmailPermissionDTO(
                EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                "topic1",
                "1995-09-09"))` ?

Comment: @Bruno: storePermission method was called 2 times on emailPermissionModel, but each time with a different EmailPermissionDTO, how can o verify both EmailPermissionDTO are expected?

Comment: Just do 2 verifications `verify(emailPermissionModel).storePermission(expectedDto1); verify(emailPermissionModel).storePermission(expectedDto2);`